# how to know the domain used in keystore/truststore?

Tags: java, web-applications, https, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I have self signed certificates for my https protocol based web application.but I want to know the domain mentioned in the keystore/truststore.
can any one help me to know it?

Answer (score 4):

List certificates in keystore using following command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore yourkeystorefile -storepass keystorepassword
```

Find your certificate and check the common name (CN) value in "Owner" tag. This is the domain name the certificate is created for.

Alternative domain names you may use are listed in optional SubjectAlternativeName section.

Answer (score 1):

Before adding new certificates in keystore or truststore its good to see, count and verify already installed certificates. run following keytool command to get a list of certififcates from keystore:

```
javin@localhost:C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/security keytool -list -keystore cacerts
Enter keystore password:  changeit

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 76 entries

digicertassuredidrootca, 07/01/2008, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 87:CE:0B:7B:2A:0E:49:00:E1:58:71:9B:37:A8:93:72
trustcenterclass2caii, 07/01/2008, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): CE:78:33:5C:59:78:01:6E:18:EA:B9:36:A0:B9:2E:23
```

You see currently keystore "cacerts" holds 76 certificates.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/add-list-certficates-java-keystore.html#ixzz39n3jfusy